# What is the meaning of $f : x \mapsto -1 +\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{2x}{3})$?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a function of domain $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
>
> $f : x \mapsto -1 +\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{2x}{3})$

What does this expression mean?

Comment: Nitpicking, but isn't it rather $$f\colon x\mapsto -1+\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)$$? (note the slightly different arrow)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes you're right, I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by DeepSea is correct, but I simply want to clarify the notation.

Usually, one can denote a map $f$ as, for example, $x\mapsto x^2$ (meaning, we map $x$ to $x^2$). This is just a fancy way to say $f(x)=x^2$, and it's not an uncommon way to denote a function.

---

Also, "$:$" usually means "such that", as in for example:

$$\exists n\in\Bbb N:n^2=16$$

Which means: "There exists an $n$ in the naturals *such that* $n^2=16$".

---

So with that in mind,

> $$f : x \rightarrow -1 +\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{2x}{3})$$

Would make sense (although the arrow $\to$ differs from $\mapsto$), since it just means "$f$ is a function such that $x$ is being mapped to $-1 +\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{2x}{3})$".

Answer (score 4):

It means $f(x) = -1+\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{2x}{3}\right)$

Comment: Really? Sometimes I really hate my book. Thanks man.

Comment: By the way, what does the : mean?

Comment: the : is a way of saying $f$ is defined from one region to another. Though it's weird for it to look like that.

Comment: @Sentinel135 the $:$ just means the usual "such that"

Comment: then is $:=$ defined such that? if so I apologize

Comment: No, I believe $:=$ is a separate symbol. On its own, $:$ means "such that".